# Can EclEmma be used with obfuscated jar file

Tags: code-coverage

Can EclEmma eclipse plugin be used for code coverage with obfuscated (with Proguard) jar file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this makes sense, because the source files would have to be obfuscated too, to generate an appropriate report.

A report is always generated using the source files of the project and these must match the class files exactly.

I don't think that you want to look at a coverage report of obfuscated code.

Comment: I am trying to run code coverage tool with a test suite that tests the jar file. in other words, I want to see how my test suite covers the functionality the jar file provides. So I wondered whether I can cover this jar file which is actually an obfuscated jar file.

Comment: hm, when jar jar file is obfuscated you will only see how much is covered but not what. Is that desired?
Basically it should work if you add the jar file to the classpath of the project and check/click the jar file in the eclemma runtime configuration.